# Can I score Pincode on the basis of financial data?

Tags: categorical-data, finance, scoring-rules

I have a financial dataset on distinct Pincode level, one of the feature is pincode and other are delinquency, cheque bounce, delinquency amount etc. I am looking to build a model where I can score pincode on the basis of features and generate a scorecard. I am trying to do clustering here, but I don't know what else I can try ?

Comment: What is a pin code? Is it the number you enter into an automated teller machine to get money? Or something else? // have you tried clustering on the features that you’ve outlined? Does it work? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your target variable (which you would like to predict or classify) is and the predictors available. If the target variable is `pincode`, you could use clustering to visualize delinquency and its relationship with location. However, if you wish to predict `delinquency`, you can use regression ([OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), [GLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model)) to obtain an equation quantifying the relationship between `delinquency` and the other predictors.